# Validate email and pass using Ajax, php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I need to know where is the error in this function? Is created to validate email and password in a simple login form...

```
function check_login(){
    // ID Name of the button used to validate
    $("#bt_login").click(function(){

        // creating a variable for email and password inputs
        var email    = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        // If input is left blank and you hit login, nothing happens
        if(email == "" && password == ""){          
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    url: "checklogin.php",
                    data: "email="+ email ,
                    data: "password="+ password ,
                    success: function(html){
                        if(data) {
                            alert("ok");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Wrong email and password");
                        }
                    }
            })

        return false;

        }
    })
}
```

When I click in the button to submit the form nothing happen! No errors! No nothing!

I call the function here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    doc("bt_login").addEventListener("click", check_login());        
</script>
```

"bt_login" is the name and the id of the submit button of the form

And this is my checklogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']     = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['password']  = $_POST['password'];

include('db.php');

//email & pass sent from form 
$email     = $_POST['email']; 
$password  = $_POST['password']; 

//to protect MySQL injection
$email     = stripslashes($email);
$password  = stripslashes($password);

$email    = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '$email' and password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1){    
    //header("location:xxx.html");
    //echo "ok";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Email and Password Exist!"); </script>';
    }
    else {
        //header("location:xxx.html");
        //echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Wrong Email or Password"); </script>';      
        }
?>
```

Comment: And where you call this function? Show the code for submit (form).

Comment: No errors in your console either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an event handler (via jquery) in a function block. Calling the function just registers the handler. Remove the function block, and the additional `addEventListener` line:

```
$("#bt_login").click(function(){

    // creating a variable for email and password inputs
    var email    = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    // If input is left blank and you hit login, nothing happens
    if(email == "" && password == ""){          
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                url: "checklogin.php",
                data: {email: email ,password: password },
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.success) {
                        console.log(response.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(response.error);
                    }
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
        })

    return false;

    }
})
```

In your php you should send json data, not script tags:

```
$response = [];
if($count == 1){    
    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Email and Password Exist';
}
else {
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['error'] = 'Wrong Email or Password';
}
//set header and return json
header('Content-Type: application/json');
die(json_encode($response));
```

Also you define the data property of the ajax request twice, which is incorrect, and your success callback receives a variable named `html` but you then check `data`.

I have changed that to `response` to match the variable name in the php - this is not necessary, but makes the code a little easier to understand

Comment: I tried and this error appear now in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: @abelvf see my edit, fixed a couple other things. That error you are getting is due to your success callback

Comment: Steve it doesn't work, now when I click in the button always receive the alert "ok" either when the fields are empty!

Comment: See the last line of my answer - i have no idea what you are sending back. Currently any response at all will trigger OK. Edit your question to show your `checklogin.php` and i can help further

Comment: Right, well you where not sending a usefull response - see my latest edit

Comment: Steve my editor (Dreamweaver) mark that exist an error in this line: $response = [];

Comment: @abelvf that is the new array syntax available from php version 5.4 onwards. If you are using an older version of php (or your editor is too old to understand the new syntax) then you can just use the old syntax instead: `$response = array();`

Comment: exactly! Steve now I no have error in my editor and also no error in console... when I click in the button of the form nothing happen! No alerts, no error in console and no alert errors either... any suggestions please?

Comment: Arg! Probably a php error somewhere. I added an error handler to log errors to the console - see what you get now

Comment: Steve no alert errors, but this error in console appear: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: Steve this error appear: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (